# What causes increasing Memory Commit Size?

Tags: c++, windows, memory

I have a C++ program running on Windows 10. The windows task manager tells me that the commit size is increasing rapidly over time. While the working set appears to be constant.

[Screenshot of Task Manager, my program in first line, commit size ~37GB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MFF6.png)

The code has been checked for memory leaks many times by different developers, we can't find any obvious leak.

The program is a graphics and memory intense application, utilizing MFC to instantiate multiple windows. Which we use to render into with OpenGL. There is a lot copying of data going on at runtime, because we are processing images of multiple cameras.

The issue is that after ~10-15days, when the commit size exhausts the available total (paged included) memory of the system (not physical RAM), either:
a) the program will crash to desktop
b) the display driver disconnected from the GPU. And we are greeted with just black screens.

What I have tried so far:

- finding memory leaks in the code
- updating graphics driver
- updating windows 10

What kind of leak could cause only the commit size to increase? How can I prevent this issue from happening?

Comment: Thing which OS shows doesn't reflect size of memory actually used by the program. Standard library tends to keep memory freed by code (do not return it to the system) in hope that it will be needed in near future. Requesting and returning memory to system is quite expensive so this is an optimization.

Comment: Try to check if graphics resources (brushes, canvas...) are release by the application. In Windows you have to free them manually

Comment: that's a textbook memory leak. it increase only the commit size and not the working memory cause the OS can swap it out.

Comment: _The code has been checked for memory leaks many times by different developers_ How?  How did they 'check it for leaks' (there are ways...).

Comment: You and multiple developers may not have found a leak, but the symptoms you describe are quite consistent with a resource leak (either a memory leak, or a leak of some other system resource such as handles or file descriptors that are often manually created but need to be manually released). In a memory intensive program, memory leaks are an obvious possibility - but only one possibility.  In a graphics intensive program, graphical resource leakage (brushes, fonts, window handles, etc) are an obvious possibility.

Comment: Thank you for all your responses.

@Federico could you elaborate? I've tried a small test memory leak app. I can't make it increase commit size without also slightly increasing the working memory. 

char* newChar = nullptr;
int main()
{
 std::string again;
 while(again.length() == 0)
 {
  std::getline(std::cin, again);
  newChar = new char[256000];
 }

 return 0;
}

Comment: @MarcoBeninca I'm not using any brushes or MFC rendering code, I just use the MFC window as a container for OpenGL.

Comment: If you're not using raw pointers, provide 
your containers/smart pointers with a custom allocator that implements logging. That would basically be a wrapper around `std::allocator`. If there's a leak you'll see it in the log. If you depend on raw pointers then it's really hard to tell. Finally when you made 100% sure the program does not leak, provide an allocator that eventually returns/recycles the memory.

Comment: For such a scenario (Windows + OpenGL) I use a combination of Qt + OpenSceneGraph (an open source library to manage OpenGL 2.0). I managed files of Gb and very large data structures with no memory leak

Answer (score 2):

After much testing and code reviewing, I have found that there was no memory leak in my application after all. Windows reported it as such, however, after upgrading the Windows 10 build from 1909 to 21H2, all the issues went away. No more commit memory increase and no more crashing/black screening.

Answer (score 0):

What, MFC is still around? Unless you have a real need for MFC you should probably use something like [glfw](https://www.glfw.org/).

Past that, outside of using external memory leak detectors you can use the heap debug support in Visual Studio's [c runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/finding-memory-leaks-using-the-crt-library?view=vs-2022). You will need to define the following in your code.

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
```

and add

```
_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
```

somewhere after the major processing and before your program exits.

This will swap out the normal malloc and free with debug versions. You can also modify new/delete to get more information as well. These overrides should catch most of the standard library allocators. There is a lot of info in that link (more than should probably be here)

After swapping out the memory handlers you would then run your program and after it has leaked a bit shut it down. Be careful to shut it down gracefully (don't kill the process) otherwise a lot more than the actual leaks will be seen as leaks. Once you call `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` it will then dump information on everything that was not free'd. Sometimes the leaks can be a hard to find as the dump may not include the source/lines (especially if you do not override new/deletes). It will just be allocation index, size, and data information, but the docs tell you how to track it down with allocation breakpoints. By default the info will dump to VS's output window, so in general it is better to run the app from VS. There are other apps that hook the `OutputDebugMessage` call and you can also redirect it yourself, but again VS is the easiest. You will need to run debug builds in order for it to work. The debug versions of the allocators are going to be slower and increase the size of your allocations but its a small price to pay in this case (and its temporary).

If you still have issues locating the leaks then next thing to try is [GFlags - PageHeap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/gflags) , but that is a whole other topic and things are really going wrong at that point.